# Image to hex triplet(Any language)

Tags: arrays, image, colors, hex, mit-scratch

Welcome,
this is not that tough please help
I use a platform ([Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu)). I need to print an image using a pen
(You may not understand what I mean in the above if you don't know the platform BUT) 
What I need is to convert the image (below), to ***hex triplet array***.

#### [Image to be converted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaE5L.png)

(Note I don't need the above image to be converted I need to know how to convert **any** image)

#### [Hex triplet array sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Iv0a7pfgi8Qx-KkgnkTuGoUJUWbk0_40/view?usp=sharing)

note: this one(above) is only a sample.

#### [For better Understanding of hex array and image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fJZw.png)

---

> I am familiar with java ,python,javascript.... most popular language 
> Give me how to convert image to hex triplet array using any language or tool

> if you know the platform (scratch) you may get a hint [here](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/545607587/)

---

Comment: Java: ImageIO, [BufferedImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) could do it by pixel, or by raster (faster, but varies w.r.t. image type). I hope you are aware you got columns by row, where as an image has rows by column. A rotation by a quarter might be an optimisation.

Comment: @JoopEggen how to do that can you provide the answer with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Path path = Paths.get("... .png");

    System.out.println("Image: " + path);
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(path.toFile());

        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();
        for (int x = 0; x < w; ++x) {
            for (int y = 0; y < h; ++y) {
                int rgb = image.getRGB(x, y);
                System.out.printf("%06X%n", rgb & 0xFF_FF_FF);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
```

`getRGB` delivers the color in ARGB format.

Comment: Thanks i just used print writter instead of Printing to console because my IDE can't support more words to print in console

`PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
output.println(hex);`